# DropdownButton - Set value: with value NOT contained by The list of items the user can select - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dropdownbutton, flutter-dropdownbutton

I have this DropdownButton

[image]

with two items in it's List

[image]

When i Select Value 2 i'd like it to show a value not contained in the list

Like this :

[image]

Is it even possible ?

It would look something like this :

```
DropdownButton<String>(
        value: dropdownValue,
        items: <String>[
          'Value 1',
          'Value 2',
        ].map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
          return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
            value: value,
            child: Text(value),
          );
        }).toList(),
        onChanged: (String? newValue) {
          setState(() {
            dropdownValue = newValue!;

            if (dropdownValue == 'Value 2') {
              dropdownValue = 'Value Not in  list of items';
            }
          });
        },
      ),
```

---

[image]

As you can see I of course get an error if i set `dropdownValue = 'Value Not in  list of items';` as it's not in the List - but i'd like it to work :)

This works on the other hand, as expected:

```
if (dropdownValue == 'Value 2') {
  dropdownValue = 'Value 1';
}
```

as `'Value 1'` is in the List - but i'd like to display a value not in the list when i click on `Value 2`

I hope someone can help ! : )

---

*[for SEO sake here is the error]:*

```
Assertion failed:
../…/material/dropdown.dart:880
items == null ||
              items.isEmpty ||
              value == null ||
              items.where((DropdownMenuItem<T> item) {
                    return item.value == value;
                  }).length ==
                  1
"There should be exactly one item with [DropdownButton]'s value: Value Not in  list of items. \nEither zero or 2 or more [DropdownMenuItem]s were detected with the same value"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to *display* some text when `Value 2` is chosen, you can try `hint` widget.

```
  String hintValue = 'Select Value'; // ---- hint
  var dropdownValue;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            ElevatedButton(child: Text('Press here'), onPressed: null), // ---- ignore
            DropdownButton<String>(
              value: dropdownValue,
              hint: Text(hintValue), // ---- hint
              isExpanded: true,
              items: <String>[
                'Value 1',
                'Value 2',
              ].map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
                return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                  value: value,
                  child: Text(value),
                );
              }).toList(),
              onChanged: (newValue) {
                setState(() {
                  // ----- if Value 2 is selected
                  if (newValue == 'Value 2') {
                    hintValue = 'Value Not in list of items';
                  } else
                    hintValue = '$newValue';  
                });
              },
            ),
          ],
        ));
  }
```

### Output

[image]

**Note** : [Documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DropdownButton/hint.html) for using `hint` widget

Answer (score 1):

I've done this way,
the thing is we need to make sure that `Item[current] == selected item.`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyStatefulWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyStatefulWidget> createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  String dropdownValue = 'Value 1';

  List<String> values = [
    'Value 1',
    'Value 2',
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: DropdownButton<String>(
        value: dropdownValue,
        onChanged: (String? newValue) {
          setState(
            () {
              if (newValue == 'Value 2') {
                values[1] = 'Value Not in  list of items';
                dropdownValue = 'Value Not in  list of items';
              }
              if (newValue == 'Value 1') {
                dropdownValue = 'Value 1';
                values[1] = 'Value 2';
              }
            },
          );
        },
        items: values.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
          return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
            value: value,
            child: Text(value),
          );
        }).toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This way we are modifying the List ```values```, would we really want a change like that?

Comment: that's a good point i forgot.  and i prefer your answer.

Comment: I have to say i like this answer too, it could prove useful, but it’s true that @abdev answer is more correct regarding my question